# Change the cron value inside the @Schduled annotation after each execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to change the value of `cron` dynamically after each execution of the method `execute`

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class PendingOrderScheduler {

    private final Logger logger;
    private final OrderService orderService;

    public PendingOrderScheduler(Logger logger, OrderService orderService) {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/1 * * * * *")
    public void execute() {
        logger.info(String.format("Executed at %s", new Date()));
        this.orderService.updatePendingOrder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use `@Scheduled` annotation if you want to configure the scheduling of job at runtime.You can use custome scheduler as described in [spring documentation.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling)

To change the configuration you need to cancel the current scheduling and create new one using [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) object of task scheduler.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, actually i have tried that, and the Job stops before it executes. I have used ScheduledFuture

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, changing cron inside cron is impossible.

You can use SchedulingConfigurer to achieve this, but @Scheduled annotation will be removed.

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class PendingOrderScheduler implements SchedulingConfigurer{

    private Map<String,CronTask> cronTasks = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler());
        this.taskRegistrar = taskRegistrar;
        addCronTask();
    }

    private CronTask addCronTask(){
        CronTask task = new CronTask(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                logger.info(String.format("Executed at %s", new Date()));
                this.orderService.updatePendingOrder();
            }
        }, "*/1 * * * * *"); //read it from some variable
        cronTasks.put("CRON_KEY", task);
        return task;
    }

    public void changeCron(){ //call it when you whant to change chron
        synchronized (PendingOrderScheduler.class) {
            List<CronTask> crons = taskRegistrar.getCronTaskList();
            taskRegistrar.destroy(); //important, cleanups current scheduled tasks
            taskRegistrar.setCronTasksList(new ArrayList<CronTask>());
             for (CronTask cron : crons) {
                if (!cronTasks.containsValue(cron)) {
                    taskRegistrar.addCronTask(cron); //copy croned by @Scheduled tasks as is
                }
            }               
            addCronTask();
            taskRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(); //rebuild
        }
    }   
}
```

Also, you can look at Quartz library, which supports cron change.